# Writing columns in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to write a txt from the results of a post process routine. I want to write the output as:

```
iteration:        1   2   3     
coordinates
0 0              1.1  3  1.4
1 1              1.2  4   0
2 3              5    7  0.5
4 5              6    9  0.2
```

However when I do not know ho to set the space between the coordinates vector and my matrix so the results is :

```
iteration:        1   2   3     
coordinates
0 0    1.1  3  1.4
1 1    1.2  4   0
2 3     5    7  0.5
4 5     6    9  0.2
```

using the fprint() function. What I do is:

```
fid = fopen('output.txt','w')
fprintf('%s %f %f',fid,[header runNumber])
%write matrix
fprintf(%f %f %f %f %f,fid,[coordinates matrix])
fclose(fid)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably open the file as type 'wt'.

```
fid = fopen('output.txt','wt')
```

[source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/249162)

If you want tab delimited, put a '\t' between each '%f' in your 'fprintf' statement.